# Performance -> Caching

Tags: caching, performance

In Configuration > Development > Performance, in the Caching area, [Cache pages for anonymous users] and [Cache blocks] are unchecked. When I check them and save, the page reloads and both boxes are again unchecked. Is this wrong? Shouldn't they "remember" the state?

Comment: Is this a site you had total control over, or did you inherit it?

Comment: How'd you guess. It's an inheritance :(

Comment: @MPD Hah, I thought exactly the same thing :) Rick, have a look in custom modules/themes for anything implementing `hook_form_alter()` or `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`, and see if anything's targeting the `system_performance_settings` form. If that fails look in the `system_performance_settings()` function, and the associated validation/submit handlers, and see if that's been changed by the previous devs. If you're unsure, install [Hacked!](https://drupal.org/project/hacked) to help out with that.

Answer (score 4):

In general, yes, the form should update with the values you set.  However, there are few different ways you can override form settings.

The two in question are `cache` and `block_cache`.  You need to search the files for lines that look like:

```
$conf['cache'] = FALSE;
$conf['block_cache'] = FALSE;
```

The integer `0` or the string `'0'` or `"0"` may be used instead.  Checking the settings.php for the site, and any custom modules.

Comment: Actually this is more likely than what I said. Can't imagine why someone would disable caching except to cover up a mistake, though

Comment: @Clive User Agent detection on the server side, views w/ random sorts, and tricky invalidations are three things that complicate the standard page cache.

Comment: Yeah there are plenty of valid use cases for having cache switched off, but doing it in such a way as to _disable_ it being turned back on again is a new one on me